# Keep values in select tag (for loop) after submit for months

Tags: php

I am trying to keep values in select tag (for loop) after submitting if the are errors in the form for months my code is

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-2">
  <label style="color:transparent;" id="test_color">h</label>
  <select name="month" id="month" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Month</option>
    <?php for($m=1; $m<=12; ++$m): ?>
      <option value="<?=date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1));?>"<?php if (isset($month) && $month==$m) echo "selected";?>>
      <?=date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1));?></option>
    <?php endfor; ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work ...

Comment: You are setting the variable $month to be a text string of the month, but the variables $m is the numeric representation.  therefore your clause `$month==$m` will never trigger.

Comment: So, what should I do ?? What is the suitable code to do this ??

Comment: try replacing `if (isset($month) && $month==$m)` with `if (isset($month) && $month==date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1)))'`

Comment: Thank you so much !!! It works !!!